# Galois Extension and Principal ideal in $F[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

We're given that $K/F$ is a Galois extension, and $[K:F]= n.$  We fix $\alpha \in K$ with minimal
polynomial $m_{\alpha}$. Now, we define a linear transformation of F-vector spaces $\mu_{\alpha}: K \rightarrow K $ by the rule $\mu_{\alpha}(x) = \alpha x$. Show that for $f ∈ F[x]$ we have that 
$f(\mu_{\alpha}) = 0$ iff  $f(x) \in (m_{\alpha}(x)).$

I was able to prove that if $f(\mu_{\alpha}) = 0$, then $f(x) \in (m_{\alpha}(x)).$ However, I am stuck with the converse part. Could you give me some hints? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $$\underbrace{\mu_{\alpha}\circ\mu_{\alpha}\circ\cdots\circ\mu_{\alpha}}_{n\,\text{times}}=\mu_{\alpha^n}.$$
So, $m_{\alpha}(\mu_{\alpha})=\mu_{m_{\alpha}(\alpha)}=0.$ If $f=gm_{\alpha}$, then $f(\mu_{\alpha})=gm_{\alpha}(\mu_{\alpha})=0.$

Comment: Is this true for any extension? I don't see why Galois extension is necessary. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, $\alpha\in K$ should be algebraic over $F$.

Comment: Thank you. So, we basically using the fact that Galois Extension is Algebraic Extension. Am I correct? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, you're right.